# Disable "ping" response in Apache

Tags: apache, ping

I saw that many sites don't respond at "ping call"; I  read that is possible disable this function in Server Apache.

My questions are very easy:
- Is it a good choose? If yes, why?

Thanks

Comment: Apart from removing an attack vector for a DDOS-attack, I do not see the value in disabling it. Being able to ping your server is an useful diagnostic tool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this has nothing to do with the apache software. The network service is answering the ICMP-Protocol, which means the PING-command. This happens on the operation systems level.

There are tutorials how to do this on Linux. (e.g. http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/40/).
Also there are tutorials how to do this on Windows (e.g. http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc786463(v=ws.10).aspx)

There are lots of goals to disable it. To pronounce an example, there could be a lower threat of flooding.